# What's the difference between a Primary Token and an Impersonation Token

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-security

Some Windows APIs return a primary token and some return an impersonation token. Some APIs require a primary token while others require an impersonation token.

For example, [`LogonUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) usually returns a primary token, except when using `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` as the logon type (`dwLogonType`):

> In most cases, the returned handle is a primary token that you can use in calls to the CreateProcessAsUser function. However, if you specify the LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK flag, LogonUser returns an impersonation token that you cannot use in CreateProcessAsUser unless you call DuplicateTokenEx to convert it to a primary token.

[`SetThreadToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379590(v=vs.85).aspx) requires an impersonation token while [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx) which seems to do pretty much the same thing takes either one.

[`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`CreateProcessWithTokenW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682434(v=vs.85).aspx) both require a primary token and both note a primary token can be acquired from an impersonation token by calling [`DuplicateTokenEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617(v=vs.85).aspx), but what do the token types **mean**?

The glossary says the following:

> [**access token**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721532(v=vs.85).aspx#_security_access_token_gly)
>
> An access token contains the security information for a logon session. The system creates an access token when a user logs on, and every process executed on behalf of the user has a copy of the token. The token identifies the user, the user's groups, and the user's privileges. The system uses the token to control access to securable objects and to control the ability of the user to perform various system-related operations on the local computer. There are two kinds of access token, primary and impersonation.
>
> [**primary token**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721603(v=vs.85).aspx#_security_primary_token_gly)
>
> An access token that is typically created only by the Windows kernel. It may be assigned to a process to represent the default security information for that process.
>
> [**impersonation token**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721588(v=vs.85).aspx#_security_impersonation_token_gly)
>
> An access token that has been created to capture the security information of a client process, allowing a server to "impersonate" the client process in security operations.

But that's not entirely useful. It seems like somebody wanted to use big boy words like "kernel" but this only serves to raise more questions such as what else (besides being assigned to a process) can a primary token be used for and who else besides the kernel can create access tokens?

(Do they mean it the the Microsoft sense where the Kernel is only part of what runs in kernel-mode and there's also the Executive etc. or do they mean that user-mode code can also create tokens? Regardless, even if a user-mode code can create tokens it will have to do it through a system-call, as with any Object Manager object, so the token will actually be created in kernel mode anyway.)

Anyway, this doesn't answer the fundamental question: What the difference between the token types? **Not** what they **may** be used for or how they are **usually** created.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A friend referred me to [*Programming Windows Security*](http://pluralsight.com/books/pws/) by Keith Brown, which answers this question exactly.

Primary tokens can and should be called process tokens, and impersonation tokens can and should be called thread tokens. Primary tokens can only be attached to processes, and impersonation tokens can only be attached to threads. That's all. They can indeed be freely converted using `DuplicateTokenEx` (assuming you have the necessary access rights to the handle you wish to convert, obviously).

From page 115 in the book:

> ```
> BOOL DuplicateTokenEx(
>   HANDLE ExistingToken,                   // in
>   DWORD   DesiredAccess,                  // in
>   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Attributes,       // in, optional
>   SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL ImpLevel,  // in
>   TOKEN_TYPE Type,                        // in
>   PHANDLE NewToken);                      // out
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The *`Type`* parameter is a historical artifact. If you look at the definition of the `TOKEN_TYPE` enumeration, you'll find that tokens have been taxonomized into two categories: impersonation versus primary tokens. Don't get hung up on this nomenclature; the meaning is actually much simpler than it sounds. Impersonation tokens can only be attached to threads, and primary tokens can only be attached to processes. That's all it means. The process token obtained earlier via `OpenProcessToken` was therefore a primary token.
>
> In very early versions of Windows NT (3.x), there were much more severe restrictions on what you could do with a token, depending on where you originally got it from, and hence the token type was introduced to track the intended usage of the token. Because this text assumes you're using Windows NT 4.0 or greater, just think of an impersonation token as a "thread token", and a primary token as a "process token", and use `DuplicateTokenEx` to convert between the two whenever necessary. Windows NT 4.0 tore down the boundaries between the two by introducing `DuplicateTokenEx`; the Windows NT 3.x version of this function, `DuplicateToken`, was hardcoded to only produce impersonation tokens. In fact, now you should be able to see the silly bug that causes the first call to `SetThreadToken` to fail: the code is attempting to attach a primary token (the one obtained from the process) to a thread (which requires an impersonation token). That's a no-no. To fix both the logical problem and the silly historical problem, here's the corrected code:

Other stuff, which aren't strictly an answer to the question, but were mentioned in the question:

- Apparently `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` goes the extra mile and converts primary tokens to impersonation tokens, while `SetThreadToken` doesn't bother. Why? Who knows? Probably for the same reason some APIs enable privileges for the duration of the call, while others require callers to enable the privileges on their own.
- `LogonUser` (and `LsaLogonUser`) probably return impersonation tokens for network logons, because of the assumption of who usually perform network logons (p. 83 onwards, for example).
- You can create tokens from user mode using the undocumented NTDLL function `ZwCreateToken`, which requires pretty unusual privileges (specifically, the unique `SE_CREATE_TOKEN_NAME` privilege). You probably shouldn't...

Comment: You can also create tokens from user mode with the documented CreateToken and CreateTokenEx functions, but you need a lot of infrastructure to do so, since those functions can only be called from SSP/APs ("security support provider/authentication package").

Comment: Good point. Note that not only they require you to implement all the SSP/AP interface (have the functions `SpLsaModeInitialize` should return in the function table, etc.), unlike 'plain' SSPs, SSP/APs run as part of LSASS, so they run under the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account and have the `SeCreateTokenPrivilege`, `SeTcbPrivilege`, etc. anyway. So security-wise they have the same requirements (you might even say that `ZwCreateToken` is less demanding), though you're correct in noting that they are documented which is a plus.

Comment: What will happen to the thread once the impersonation tokens is disposed?

Comment: @conio I think he mean: obtain an impersonation token somehow, attach it to a thread, and `CloseHandle` the token. What will happen to the thread?

Comment: @raymai97: Nothing. That's the correct flow. Like the rest of the kernel object, access tokens are reference counted. Attaching a token to a thread increases its reference count, with the thread owning the reference. Calling `CloseHandle` closes *your* handle and releases the reference *you* own.

Comment: What will happen to an impersonated thread once a session of a logged-on user that is the source of the access token for the thread is closed?

Comment: @arabesc, more or less nothing. Like the rest of the Windows Kernel objects, the token is valid as long as there are references to it and a thread impersonating a token is holding a reference to it. Also note that you're probably mixing up _logon sessions_ and _Terminal Services sessions_. A _logon session_ is what you get when you call `LogonUser` or something similar and it won't be closed until all the tokens it backs up by are destroyed. A _Terminal Services session_ is mostly unrelated to this and "logging out of Windows" (which terminates it) does nothing to the existing logon sessions.